# how to Check if Angular Reactive form has any value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular reactive form with 5 controls. Along with that, I have a reset button. When the reset button is clicked if the form is not empty I want to show a confirm dialog. If the form is empty I will simply reset the form.

**Question** Is there any way to check if the reactive form is blank or it has any value.

```
this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    id: new FormControl(''),
    isAdmin: new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]),
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    details: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Comment: You can check each field if is not **""** || false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the dirty property of your FormGroup :

```
this.userForm.dirty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const form = this.fb.group({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      isAdmin: new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]),
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      details: new FormControl(''),
  });

    const formValue = form.value;
    // Although in this case it'd be semantically better to use .reduce, but for the sake of simplicity I'd prefer to use combination of .map + .some. If you're not afraid of .reduce, you can apply it here. 
    const mapped = Object.values(formValue).map(value => !!value);
    const hasValues = mapped.some(value => value);
```

But maybe you're looking for another solution (just to check whether a form was touched or not). In this case you can stick with form.dirty (although it won't work if a user deletes previously entered data) or form.invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you´re looking for this:

```
onSave(): void {
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.userForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    // do what you want to save
}
```

Regards